# Dynamically create env file laravel

Tags: laravel, environment-variables, laravel-6

My customer wants that i create multiple env files according to the url so that we only have the project in one main folder.

The user will access example.software.com and the laravel framework detects the url and creates and env file for that subdomain.

The goal is that when the env file is created the user will automatically have access only to his own invoices, the database is already prepared for that.

Is that dynamic env file creation possible?

Comment: Most unsafe idea I've read today so far.

Comment: Sounds like overkill... A system with a proper invoices table, linked to clients/users/whatever you call your entities, with a proper authentication system should be plenty to handle security/privacy concerns around said invoices. Not to mention, I'm not even sure how Laravel would handle multiple `.env` files like that... You can't really load them on the fly per-se.

Comment: This would also mean you deploy your laravel app to all subdomains? It's a bit strange, also because you say that Laravel already detects the subdomain, so it has already loaded an env/config. You can however dynamically set config options of course. I guess you're looking for something like multi tenancy. There are several packages available to do what you want.

Comment: Multiple env files is not how you achieve this.